# Disable submit button until one in a group of dynamically-created radio buttons selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, razor

I would like to disable a submit button until one of a group of radio buttons is selected. I **know** there are similar questions out there, but none pertain to a dynamically-created group of radio buttons...

Here is what I have.. a script at the top of the page generates a number of buttons given a user upload in a previous view:

```
var jScriptArray = new Array(@ViewBag.ColNames.Length);
var array = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.ColNames));
for( var i = 0; i < @ViewBag.ColNames.Length; i++ ) {
    jScriptArray[i] = array[i];
}
var length = @(ViewBag.NCols);
$(document).ready(function () {
     for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
           $('#radioGroupBy').append('<input id="grp' + i +'" type="radio" name="group" value="'+i+'">'+jScriptArray[i]+'</input>')
           $('#radioGroupBy').append('<p style="padding:0px;margin:0px;"></br></p>');
     }
});
```

This works, and selecting any of the buttons returns the proper value; great.  However, I want to disable the submit button until one of these radio buttons is selected.  Using an answer I found on SO earlier, I created the following (this works, but only if I hard code the group of buttons. The issue is it *won't* work with the Javascript-created group):

```
var $radioButtons = $("input[name='group']");
    $radioButtons.change(function () {
        var anyRadioButtonHasValue = false;
        // iterate through all radio buttons
        $radioButtons.each(function () {
            if (this.checked) {
                // indicate we found a radio button which has a value
                anyRadioButtonHasValue = true;
                // break out of each loop
                return false;
            }
        });
        // check if we found any radio button which has a value
        if (anyRadioButtonHasValue) {
            // enable submit button.
            $("input[name='submitbtn']").removeAttr("disabled");
        }
    });
```

Also, for the sake of thoroughness, here is the submit button:

```
<input id="submitbtn" name="submitbtn" type="submit" value="Drill Down" disabled="disabled" />
```

Thanks so much!

Comment: On submit, check if any of the desired radios is checked, if not don't do anything, else submit. Also, when are you using the jquery for the radio buttons, it should come after your dynamically created radio buttons are appended

Comment: Once the buttons have been added to the DOM, there's no difference between them and a manually generated group of buttons. When are you actually defining the variable radioButtons?

Comment: @BenjaminVisness, I am defining the radio buttons right away (document.ready...). I am thinking this is likely on the right path of where the error lies, however - if once added to the DOM there is no difference, the latter script must be executing before they are even added...

Comment: @Tgsmith61591 Where are you actually running the script then? It would need to come after the other code in $(document).ready().

Comment: Hi Benjamin, thanks for your response -- see my solution below. I ended up figuring it out thanks to you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. As Benjamin suggested in comments above, the latter script was executing before the DOM was ready.  I solved it by just surrounding the whole script in $(window).load... :

```
$(window).load(function () {
    var $radioButtons = $("input[name='group']");
    $radioButtons.change(function () {
        var anyRadioButtonHasValue = false;
        // iterate through all radio buttons
        $radioButtons.each(function () {
            if (this.checked) {
                // indicate we found a radio button which has a value
                anyRadioButtonHasValue = true;
                // break out of each loop
                return false;
            }
        });
        // check if we found any radio button which has a value
        if (anyRadioButtonHasValue) {
            // enable submit button.
            $("input[name='submitbtn']").removeAttr("disabled");
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Event delegation (also, use `.prop()` when removing the `disabled` property to the submit button)

```
$("#radioGroupBy").on("change", ":radio[name=group]", function() {
    var $radioButtons = $(":radio[name=group]");
    var anyRadioButtonHasValue = false;
    // iterate through all radio buttons
    $radioButtons.each(function () {
        if (this.checked) {
            // indicate we found a radio button which has a value
            anyRadioButtonHasValue = true;
            // break out of each loop
            return false;
        }
    });
    // check if we found any radio button which has a value
    if (anyRadioButtonHasValue) {
        $("input[name='submitbtn']").prop("disabled", false);
    }
});
```